# AWS CodeBuild, buildspec.yml "bad substitution" error

Tags: bash, aws-codebuild

I'm using AWS CodeBuild, and I need to manipulate an environment variable. I originally tried using a bash pattern substitution, like this, in the `buildspec.yml`:

```
  build:
    on-failure: ABORT
    commands:
      - env="${CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER/tag\//}"
```

`CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER` should be something like `tag/my-tag-name`, and I want to remove the `tag/` part of it. This command works fine from a local bash shell, but when performned in CodeBuild, this is the output:

```
[Container] 2021/08/02 21:29:28 Running command env="${CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER/tag\//}"
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: Bad substitution
...
[Container] 2021/08/02 21:29:28 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: env="${CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER/tag\//}". Reason: exit status 2
```

I ended up replacing the pattern substitution with an `awk` command just to get it working, but it makes for more complex code. And I don't understand why the pattern substitution doesn't work?

Here's the awk command I ended up using, which is working fine:

```
  build:
    on-failure: ABORT
    commands:
      - env="`echo $CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER | awk -F/ '$1=="tag" {print $2;}'`"
```

Comment: Thanks @Philippe, that works! If you add as an answer I'll be happy to accept and upvote it.

Comment: It's probably using the dash shell to run the command. Substitution with `${var/pattern/replacement}` is an extension to the standard shell syntax, and is supported by ksh, bash, and zsh, but not by more basic shells like dash. `${var#pattern}`, on the other hand, is part of the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), and will work in any POSIX-compliant shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeBuild might not be using bash. Try this :

```
env="${CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER#tag/}"
```

Answer (score 5):

Gordon's comment on the original post above explains why this happens - that bash extensions won't work on more basic shells (and it appears that CodeBuild's Ubuntu containers may use `dash`).

However, you can force CodeBuild to use bash with the following in your buildspec:

```yaml
env:
  shell: bash
```

(documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax)

This should then allow you to use any of the substitutions supported by `bash`, and it appears to resolve this issue.

(Alternatively, if you're calling a separate shell script from your buildspec, you can just ensure that you have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Examples) at the top of it).